# Haskell scripts to solve identity matrix

Tags: haskell

how to solve identity for a matrix using Haskell scripts?
For example, if with this given type

```
 type Matrice a = [[a]]
 identity :: Int -> Maybe (Matrice Int)
```

How can it return the identity matrice for the given size? I know that identity matrice is a square matrice which has zero for all values, except the values on the top-left to bottom-right diagonal which are all one. With the condition of, if the size is less than 1, then the identity matrice isn't defined and Nothing is returned.

So say for example,

```
Prelude > identity 5
          Just [[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1]]
Prelude > identity 2
          Just [[1,0],[0,1]]
```

I've tried

```
identity1 :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
identity1 a b
    | a == 0 []
    | b == 0 (1:identity (a-1) (-1))
    | otherwise = (0:identity' (a-1) (b-1))

identity2 :: Int -> Int -> Matrice Int
identity2 a b
    | b == 0 []
    | otherwise = (0:identity1 (a-1) (b-1) : identity2 a (b-1)
```

Comment: The single form of the word *matrices* is *matrix*, not *matrice*.
Anyways, how is the type `Matrice` defined? Is it `newtype Matrice a = [[a]]` ?

Comment: yes, sorry my bad

Comment: What did you try yourself. Can you for example come up with an algorithm in pseudocode to handle this?

Comment: @lisyarus: you probably mean `type Matrice a = [[a]]`. `newtype` requires a dataconstructor.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

One short approach is to define the "infinite" identity matrix as

```
ii = (1 : repeat 0) : fmap (0:) ii
```

The first row is `1 0 0 ...`; each subsequent row is the row above it with a 0 prepended to it.

It should be obvious that the first n rows of the first n columns of the infinite identity matrix is **I**<sub>*n*</sub>.

```
1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
--+   |   |   |   |   |
0   1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
------+   |   |   |   |
0   0   1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
----------+   |   |   |  ...
0   0   0   1 | 0 | 0 |
--------------+   |   |
0   0   0   0   1 | 0 |
------------------+   |
0   0   0   0   0   1 |
----------------------+
           .            .
           .              .
           .                .
```

Given that, we just use `take` to obtain the appropriate-sized sub matrix. `take n` applied to each row will return the first `n` columns, and `take n` applied to the result takes just the first `n` rows.

```
type Matrix a = [[a]]

identity :: Int -> Maybe (Matrix Int)
identity n | n <= 0 = Nothing
           | otherwise = let ii = (1:repeat 0) : (fmap (0:) ii)
                         in Just $ take n (take n <$> ii)
```

---

If recursively defined infinite lists tie your brain in knots, you can also just define an `enlarge` function that generates **I**<sub>*n*+1</sub> from **I**<sub>*n*</sub>. To do so, it is convenient to assume that **I**<sub>0</sub> exists and is represented as an empty list.

```
enlarge :: Matrix Int -> Matrix Int
enlarge [] = [[1]]
enlarge i@(r:_) = (1:(0<$r)) : fmap (0:) i
```

Then you can define `identity :: Int -> Matrix Int` by indexing an infinite list of identity matrices

```
identity n | n <= 0 = Nothing
identity n = Just (identities !! n)
```

where `identities :: [Matrix Int]` is built with either `iterate`

```
identities = iterate enlarge []
```

or `Data.List.unfoldr`:

```
identities = unfoldr (\x -> Just (x, enlarge x)) []
```

It's also worth noting that the infinite identity matrix is the fixed point of `enlarge`:

```
import Data.Function
ii = fix enlarge
```

Comment: Beautiful. The in-memory structure for the infinite matrix is a lovely one to hold in one's head; and can represent O(n^2) elements in just O(n) space. It is a shame that this property can't be reproduced in the finite case -- at least, not by standard lists.

Comment: @DanielWagner, `Data.Sequence` should come fairly close (linearithmic, I think; possibly better) if you do it with `inits`, `tails`, and `zipWith (><)`. But no, those are not standard lists.

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, and a `ByteString`-like representation (an array plus a slice) can do it for real with no "arithmic" in your linearity. Ah well!

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think slicing is a bit of a cheat. From a theoretical standpoint, it requires a RAM machine rather than just a pointer machine. From a practical standpoint, slicing can retain memory that will never be accessed again. I've verified that the algorithm I sketched is tightly linearithmic (the big term looks like `log (n!)`). I'm not sure if there's a faster way.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I found a rather simpler (but non-incremental) way to do it with sequences in linear time (just rotate a bunch of times). Now I'm trying to see if I can make diagonal matrices incrementally in linear time by digging into the internals and playing with Wasserman's `inits`.

Answer (score 4):

One way to accomplish this is through recursion.

I'm going to ask you some leading questions, since I haven't seen what you've tried so far:

- What's the identity for 1x1 matrices?
- Given the identity for nxn matrices, what would you need to add to create the identity for (n+1)x(n+1) matrices?

Or in pseudo-code:

```
identity 1 = Just $ _1x1_identity
  -- _1x1_identity :: [[Int]]

identity n_plus_1 | n_plus_1 > 1 = fmap _alter_identity (identity n)
  where n = n_plus_1 - 1
  -- _alter_identity :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]

identity n | n < 1 = Nothing
```

If you're unfamiliar with `fmap`, it's used here to unwrap/rewrap the `Maybe` value returned from the other call to `identity`.

I could do the same more verbosely as

```
identity n_plus_1 | n_plus_1 > 1 = case identity n of
    Nothing     -> Nothing
    Just matrix -> Just (_alter_identity matrix)
  where n = n_plus_1 - 1
```

---

Your approach in the comments attempts to construct the entire matrix row by row, which is also workable.

One way to implement that approach more directly is through a list comprehension.

List comprehensions make it easy to define new lists and lists of lists:

```
Prelude> [ i | i <- [0..4] ]
[0,1,2,3,4]
Prelude> [ [(i,j) | j <- [0..3]] | i <- [0..2] ]
[ [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)]
, [(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)]
, [(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
]
```

Above we can see that we can use a list comprehension to generate a matrix of coordinates - the value `(i,j)` shows up in the `i`'th row and the `j`th column.

List comprehensions allow you to place arbitrary expressions on the left-hand-side of the `|`, so I could do `i + j` instead of `(i,j)` to get a very different matrix:

```
Prelude> [ [i + j | j <- [0..3]] | i <- [0..2] ]
[ [0,1,2,3]
, [1,2,3,4]
, [2,3,4,5]
]
```

That's a rectangular matrix. A square matrix would use the same bounds for `i` and `j`.

If you were to use a list comprehension like that to create a square matrix, what expression would you put to the left hand side of the `|` to create the identity matrix?  To put it another way, can you express the identity matrix's value at row `i` column `j` in terms of `i` and `j`?

Comment: identity1 :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
    identity1 a b | a == 0 []
              | b == 0 (1:identity (a-1) (-1))
       | otherwise = (0:identity' (a-1) (b-1))

identity2 :: Int -> Int -> Matrice Int 
identity2 a b | b == 0 []
                     | otherwise = (0:identity1 (a-1) (b-1) : identity2 a (b-1)

Comment: I used identity helper but is there any easier way to do this? I'm aware of the funtction fmap but i don't know how to use it in this context

Comment: @Anna: `_1x1_identity` is just a constant, so no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In case one needs some iterative approach in Haskell, recursion is used. This means that we need to define base case(s) as well as inductive case(s).

There are two base cases here:

1. the value is less than or equal to zero, in that case the value is `Nothing`;
2. the case where the value is exactly one, in that case we return a `Just` with a 1×1 matrix:

```
1
```

There is one inductive case: in case the number is greater than `1`, we first generate the identity matrix for `n-1`, and then we add row at the top and a column at the left:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

this means we thus need to prepend all rows of the previous matrix with `0`, and we prepend the matrix with a list that contains one `1` and `n-1` zeros.

Let us first forget about the first base case (`n` is less than or equal to zero), and assume `n` is always strictly positive. In that case there is no need to wrap the value in a `Maybe`, so we first construct a function:

```
identity' :: Int -> Matrix Int
identity' = ...
```

so the base case is where the parameter is `1`:

```
identity' 1 = ...
```

and the inductive case has shape:

```
identity' n = first_row : map prepend_zero (identity (n-1))
    where first_row = ...
          prepend_zero = ...
```

Now we can construct `identity` in terms of `identity'` by only once check whether the value is less than or equal to zero:

```
identity :: Int -> Maybe (Matrix Int)
identity n | n <= 0 = Nothing
           | otherwise = Just (identity' n)
    where identity' 1 = ...
          identity' n = first_row : map prepend_zero (identity (n-1))
              where first_row = ...
                    prepend_zero = ...
```

I leave the expressions (`...`) as an exercise that should probably be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

deconstructivism

```
identity n = splitEvery n $ (concat $ replicate (n-1) $ 1: replicate n 0)++[1]
```

proof without words

```
[[1,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,1]]  ~
[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1]            ~
[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0] ++ [1] ~
[1,0,0,0,0,0]{4} ++ [1]                                        ~
(1:[0]{5}){4} ++ [1]
```

you need to handle special cases (`n<0` and `n==1`)

Comment: `\n -> take n . splitEvery n . cycle $ 1 : replicate n 0`